# Android : Is It Possible To Show Only Quaters in Time Picker ? 00 : 15 : 30 :45

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I need to show only `[00 , 15 , 30 ,45]` in time picker i have searched but couldn't find anything , Does any one have idea how to achieve this ?

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Time Picker Does Not Provide `setInterval()` method to do that we need to work with `MaterialDateTimepicker`

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.6.3'
```

its latest version was conflicting with some of my libraries that's why i used 3.6.3

Also those who are using `NumberPicker` to do that it doesn't work for me

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(mTimePickerListener,
                    now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                    false
            );
            timePickerDialog.setThemeDark(false);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("TimePicker Title");
            timePickerDialog.setTimeInterval(1, 15, 30); // 15 Minutes Interval
          //timePickerDialog.setTimeInterval(1, 30, 60); // 30 Minutes Interval
            timePickerDialog.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
            timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                }
            });
            timePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
```

}

```
 private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom time picker by creating custom circle shape drawable and make it as a background of framelayout and to get the value of time listen to the click event of textviews

code :
bg_circle.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
   <stroke android:width="2dp"/>

   </shape>
```

layout_picker.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"
android:padding="4dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="15"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="30"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="45"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Man I needed to customize the Time Picker , Thank God After Hours of Searching got it working